# compiling and running packages of Java classes in command line?

Tags: java, command-line, compilation, package

I have a `helloworld.java` in this directory structure.

```
    bash: ls
    com
    bash: ls com/
    stack
    bash: ls com/stack/
    prog
    bash: ls com/stack/prog/helloworld.java
```

To compile I did, `javac com/stack/prog/helloworld.java`
but for running it I did,`java com.stack.prog/helloworld`

Why is it for compiling, the `/` are needed. but for running it `.` are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile your *.java file using CMD or Terminal you need to give its exact **path to that file**, and separate the directory structure in your path **by using "\" in Windows and "/" in Unix**, So, when you compile you give the path, that's why slashes are used. And once the file is compiled i.e. *.class is made, to run the code you need to run it by specifying its **package structure**. And their has to be a difference in file systems path directory structure and the package structure of java. Java makers must have used dot(.) instead of slash to bring the difference in notice. It is **same as you write the import statement** in your code (in which packages are separated by the dot(.) and not slashes). This is because by slash it means you are entering in a simple filesystem directory and **by dot(.) it means you are entering in a certain package to access a particular Java Class** defined in that package.

Comment: I was wondering, does this mean we can't use dots in folders in that path? Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

When you are compiling you are pointing to a source file by its path (that uses slashes to separate folder names). When running you are using a java namespace (also called a package+Class name) which use dots. In Java the class name must exactly match the file name. There isn't the same requirement for packages and folders though it's a good idea for keeping code organized.